# jquery check element exists

Tags: jquery, image

Is there a way to check if an image exists using jQuery?

I thought the following would work but it doesn't and console.log shows Error 404 for the image if it doesn't exist.

```
$("#icon").html("<img src='/assets/img/"+condition+".png'>");
if (!$("#icon")){
    $("#icon").html("nothing to show");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
$("#icon").html("<img src='/assets/img/"+condition+".png'>");
$("#icon img").error(function() {
       $("#icon").html("nothing to show");
    });
```

​